# Overload arithmetic & comparison operators for element-wise list operations in Python

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, operator-overloading

I have a class as:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, data: dict):
        self.data = data
```

I want to perform operations such as

```
d = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}
objA = Data(d)
objA.data['a'] + 2               # this should return element-wise addition=> [3, 4, 5]
objA.data['a'] + objA.data['b']  # this should return element-wise addition=> [5, 7, 9]
objA.data['a'] > 2               # this should return element-wise comparison=> [False, False, True]
```

How can I overload the arithmetic and comparison operators to perform element-wise operations of lists?

Comment: `numpy` can already perform these kinds of operations -- is there any reason why you want to implement them yourself?

Comment: Do you expect us to write the code for you? Show what have you tried and what particular problem you have with implementing any of these. Not to mention that expected outcome is unclear and probably should not be implemented by these specials methods.

Comment: In all of your examples it is operation on list (e.g. add list and int, add 2 lists or compare list to int. Your data class dunder methods will never be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```py
class MathList:
    def __init__(self, data: list):
        self.data = data
    
    def __add__(self, n):
        return [x + n for x in self.data]

    def __sub__(self, n):
        return [x - n for x in self.data]

    def __mul__(self, n):
        return [x * n for x in self.data]

    def __truediv__(self, n):
        return [x / n for x in self.data]

    def __eq__(self, n):
        return [x == n for x in self.data]

    def __ne__(self, n):
        return [x != n for x in self.data]

    def __lt__(self, n):
        return [x < n for x in self.data]

    def __le__(self, n):
        return [x <= n for x in self.data]

    def __gt__(self, n):
        return [x > n for x in self.data]

    def __ge__(self, n):
        return [x >= n for x in self.data]


class Data:
    def __init__(self, data: dict):
        self.data = {k: MathList(v) for k, v in data.items()}

d = Data({
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [4, 5, 6]
})

# Arithmatic operations
print(d.data['a'] + 2)  # Output: [3, 4, 5]
print(d.data['b'] - 2)  # Output: [2, 3, 4]
print(d.data['a'] * 2)  # Output: [2, 4, 6]
print(d.data['b'] / 2)  # Output: [2.0, 2.5, 3.5]

# Boolean operations
print(d.data['a'] == 2) # Output: [False, True, False]
print(d.data['b'] != 4) # Output: [False, True, True]
print(d.data['a'] < 3)  # Output: [True, True, False]
print(d.data['b'] <= 4) # Output: [True, False, False]
print(d.data['a'] > 2)  # Output: [False, False, True]
print(d.data['b'] >= 5) # Output: [False, True, True]
```

This makes a new class called `MathList` and this performs the operations you want

Edit: you might want to look at numpy, that can also do this

Comment: This cannot perform operations like `objA.data['a'] + objA.data['b']` or `objA.data['a']>3 & objA.data['b']>3`

Comment: The operators should return `Series` type instead of `list`. But then how would we perform downstream operations such as & operations between two Series?

Answer (score 0):

I have defined the `data` as a `list`

```py
class Data:
    def __init__(self, data: list):
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, x):
        self.data.append(x)
        return self

    def __sub__(self, x):
        self.data.remove(x)
        return self

    def __lt__(self, x):
        return [item < x for item in self.data]

    def __le__(self, x):
        return [item <= x for item in self.data]

    def __eq__(self, x):
        return [item == x for item in self.data]

    def __ne__(self, x):
        return [item != x for item in self.data]

    def __gt__(self, x):
        return [item > x for item in self.data]

    def __ge__(self, x):
        return [item >= x for item in self.data]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.data)


objA = Data([1, 2, 3])
objB = Data([4, 5, 6])
objA = objA + 7
print(objA)  # Output: [1, 2, 3, 7]
objA = objA - 7
print(objA)  # Output: [1, 2, 3]
print(objA < 2)  # Output: [True, False, False]
print(objA <= 2)  # Output: [True, True, False]
print(objA == 2)  # Output: [False, True, False]
print(objA != 2)  # Output: [True, False, True]
print(objA < 2)  # Output: [True, False, False]
print(objA >= 2)  # Output: [False, True, True]
```

Comment: Note that this is slightly different from what OP asks for - . instance of custom class with a data attribute that is a dict of lsits

Comment: Yes, in the question the `data` parameter of `__init__` was a dict: in yours it is a list

Comment: Also, I don't think `__add__` and `__sub__` are doing what they're meant to - in the question it wants the number added/subtracted from each number in the list - not appended/removed